# How to get list of users I have favourited and their information

Tags: php, api, laravel, laravel-5

I am building an API in Laravel 5 and want to get list of people I have favourited and their information.

### User model

```
class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract {

use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword;

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'users';

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = ['username', 'email', 'password'];

/**
 * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password',    
    'secret_key'
];

public function attribute()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\UserAttributes', 'user_id', 'id');
}

public function photos()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Photos', 'user_id', 'id');
}

public function favourites()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Favourites', 'from', 'id');
}

public function favourited()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Favourites', 'to', 'id');
}
```

### Favourites Model

```
class Favourites extends Model {

   protected $table = 'favourite';

   public function user()
   {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'from', 'id');
    }

}
```

### User Attributes Model

```
class UserAttributes extends Model {

    protected $table = 'user_attributes';

    public function user()
    {
       return $this->belongsTo('User', 'user_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

- User table holds information like username, email password etc.
- Attribute table holds information like height, weight, etc. (this is so that the user's table doesn't have 70 columns)
- Favourite table holds from and to columns. `From` is my user id and `to` is the user ID I have fvaourited.

This is what I currently have:

```
return User::with(['attribute','favourites'])->find($user_id);
```

What I want to achieve is similar to below:

```
"favourites": [
    {
        "id": "15",
        "from": "231", // My ID
        "to": "**100**", // ID of user I have favourited (FK)
        "created_date": "2013-04-10 21:35:28",
        "user": [
            "id": "**100**", // USER ID
            "username": "someuser",
            "email": "random@mail.com",
            "email_verified": "1",
            "has_photo": "1",
            "dob": "1952-11-12"
        ],
        "attribute": [
            "id": "105",
            "user_id": "**100**", // USER ID (FK)
            "height": "70",
            "car": "0",
            "pet": "2",
        ]
    }
]
```

I need my json like above so that when I call the api URL /api/v1/favourites?my_id=231 in my app or site and get all the required information rather than loading it all individually. Unless I am wrong?

If you think this way of doing this is wrong for an app, I would be more than happy to hear your input as this is something new to me.

Answer (score 0):

You certainly need to transform the data before send it. You may want to create function or a class 'UserTransformer' that will do it for you. [Fractal](http://fractal.thephpleague.com/) may help you. Incase you're Laracasts fan or new to Laravel, you certainly have missed Incremental API Series (https://laracasts.com/series/incremental-api-development).

Comment: I am now using Fractal which helped a lot.